# Check for existence of key in multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hopefully an easy question.

Why is that checking for existence of a key in a multidimensional array:

```
a = new Array(Array());
a[0][0]='1';
a[0][1]='2';
if(a[1][2] == undefined){
alert("sorry, that key doesn't exist");
} else {alert('good, your key exists');
}
```

seems not to be working in general, but it works when I check for a first index (in this case, '0') that is 'defined' by `a[0][x]`. For example, when I ask for `a[0][2]` (which is not defined), it shows the first alert. However, when I ask for `a[1][0]`, I get:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check first if the first dimension exists then if the key in the second dimension exists

The logic will return `false` if the first test returns `false`, and tests the second dimension *only* if the first one is `true`.

```
  if(a[1] == undefined && a[1][2] == undefined)
```

Comment: if first is undefined then why to check next one? If `a[1]` is undefined then obviously `a[1][2]` will be undefined. No ?

Answer (score 3):

On supported platforms, We can just do:

```
if(a[3]?.[3]){
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the first three assignments your array actually looks like this:

```
a = [['1','2']]
```

Reading `a[0][2]` just returns `undefined` because `a[0]` exists but its property `'0'` is not defined.

But trying to read `a[1][0]` throws a *TypeError* because `a[1]` is already `undefined` and isn’t an object and thus doesn’t have any properties. This is also what your error message says:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

You can solve this problem by first checking for `a[1]` and then checking for `a[1][0]` using the `typeof` operator:

```
if (typeof a[1] !== 'undefined' && typeof a[1][0] !== 'undefined')
```

Comment: In my real code, I have more than a=[['1','2']], however, I get the point. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Array(Array())
```

does not define a multi-dimensional array. It just defines an array with one item, which happens to be another (empty) array. There are no built-in multidimensional arrays in javascript, so you will have to handle things more manually.

Comment: Plus, there should be some `new` keywords in there. Calling a constructor function without new is a Bad Thing.

Comment: Well, that doesn't answer my question, however, thanks for pointing out 'new Array(Array());'. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to further qualify the conditional. Since the [1] index of the array is undefined you can't test for values in it.

```
if(a[1] === undefined || a[1][2] === undefined)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, @Caspar posted earlier (3 minutes earlier), so I must accept his answer. +1, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming explicitly `arr[i][j] = undefined` is not done

Try the below:

(Used last 2nd one today)

```
if (arr[i]?.[j] === 100) {
    // value at i & j  is 100
}

if (arr[i]?.[j] !== undefined) {
    // value at i & j  exists
}

if (arr[i]?.[j] === undefined) {
    // value at i & j  does not exist
}

if ([100, 200].includes(arr[i]?.[j])) {
    // value at i & j  is 100 or 200
}

if ([undefined, 100].includes(arr[i]?.[j])) {
    // value at i & j does not exist
    //   Or, value exists & it is 100
}

if ([undefined, 100, 200].includes(arr[i]?.[j])) {
    // value at i & j does not exist
    //   Or, value exists & it is 100 or 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = Array(Array());
a[0][0]='1';
a[0][1]='2';
if(a[1] === undefined || a[1][2] === undefined) {
    alert("sorry, that key doesn't exist");
} else {
    alert('good, your key exists');
}
```