# How to check if an array index exists or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am working with Titanium, my code looks like this:

```
var currentData = new Array();
if(currentData[index]!==""||currentData[index]!==null||currentData[index]!=='null')
{
    Ti.API.info("is exists  " + currentData[index]);
    return true;
}
else
{   
    return false;
}
```

I am passing an index to the `currentData` array. I still can't detect a non-existing index using the above code.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You need conjunctions (`&&`) between the individual conditions.

Comment: Try these checks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71808205/984471

Answer (score 527, accepted):

Use `typeof arrayName[index] === 'undefined'`

i.e.

```
if(typeof arrayName[index] === 'undefined') {
    // does not exist
}
else {
    // does exist
}
```

Comment: +1, nice. You can also use `if(arrayName[index] === 'undefined')` as a shortcut

Comment: @AnchovyLegend no, you cannot! But you can use `if(arrayName[index] === undefined)`.

Comment: this fails, if the item is there, but it's value is undefined; use this answer instead -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-array-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object-or-array

Comment: as @Matus said, there is more explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-array-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object-or-array), you should be aware on.

Comment: What if you have a 2D array? (typeof tree[4][4] === 'undefined') If [4][4] does not exist, then you will get an error that it's an undefined object.

Comment: for if(arrayName[index] === undefined) you may use even shorter one which is if(!arrayName[index])

Comment: @ParkJongBum That will only work if they understand "[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)" in JavaScript and if the array contains no falsy values. For example, if a[0] exists and is an empty string (or 0 or null or other falsy value), `!a[0]` will return true (saying the element does not exist) instead of false:
`a = ['']; if (a[0] === undefined) { console.log('not-exist') } else { console.log('exists') } ; if (!a[0]) { console.log('not-exist') } else { console.log('exists') } `

Answer (score 91):

```
var myArray = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

if (myArray.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) {
  console.log("element doesn't exist");
}
else {
  console.log("element found");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this one doesn't work in IE 7 and below.

Comment: This in my opinion is the best answer, by now IE 7 is not mainteined any more so it's not a problem. Although I will suggest to use the triple equals `if(myArray.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1)`

Comment: The OP was looking to see if the given **index** number exists. This is checking if a given **value** exists.

Answer (score 59):

These days I would take advantage of ecmascript and use it like that

```
return myArr?.[index]
```

Comment: @dsi you are allways free to check it in console. Anyway it should. Idea is exactly to save you from error on that case.

Comment: let date = string.match(/Date: (.*)/)?.[1] > SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: Wow this is brilliant, tested all the cases and working really well.

Comment: What would return if `myArr[index]` does not exists?

Answer (score 33):

This is exactly what the `in` operator is for. Use it like this:

```js
if (index in currentData) 
{ 
    Ti.API.info(index + " exists: " + currentData[index]);
}
```

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107879/579078)  is wrong, it will give a false negative if the value at `index` is `undefined`:

```js
const currentData = ['a', undefined], index = 1;

if (index in currentData) {
  console.info('exists');
}
// ...vs...
if (typeof currentData[index] !== 'undefined') {
  console.info('exists');
} else {
  console.info('does not exist'); // incorrect!
}
```

Comment: Only works on numeric index since it searches if the property exists on the object. Examaple let colors = new Array("green", "blue", "yellow"); "yellow" in colors >> false

Comment: @PolRué That's _by design_, the `in` operator checks if the _index_ exists (has an associated value as opposed to being a hole). If you want to check the membership of an element, I suggest using the `Set` type and its `.has` method

Comment: Yes, I reached that conlusion too. In my case .has worked well

Answer (score 22):

Someone please correct me if i'm wrong, but **AFAIK** the following is true:

1. Arrays are really just Objects under the hood of JS
2. Thus, they have the prototype method `hasOwnProperty` "inherited" from `Object`
3. in my testing, `hasOwnProperty` can check if anything exists at an array index.

So, as long as the above is true, you can simply:

`const arrayHasIndex = (array, index) => Array.isArray(array) && array.hasOwnProperty(index);`

usage:

`arrayHasIndex([1,2,3,4],4);` outputs: `false`

`arrayHasIndex([1,2,3,4],2);` outputs: `true`

Comment: This also works for undefined and null values in the array, which none of the other answers here do.

Comment: Verified from MDN: "If an Object is an Array, hasOwnProperty  method can check whether an index exists." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Also, `hasOwnProperty` won't return true for inherited properties like `__proto__`, this should be the answer.

Comment: This also works for arrays containing zeros and other falsy values +1.

Answer (score 6):

This also works fine, testing by type using `===` against `undefined`.

```
if (array[index] === undefined){ return } // True
```

**Test:**

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

if (fruits["Cherry"] === undefined){
  console.log("There isn't any cherry in the fruits basket :(")
}
```

Or similarly:

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

if (!fruits["Cherry"]){
  console.log("There isn't any cherry in the fruits basket :(")
}

// No errors: 
if (fruits["Cherry"]){
  console.log("There is some cherry in there!")
}
```

Comment: for cases where undefined is not expected to be a valid element in the array, i will prefer this version, as it is the most efficient way possible. only grab for my answer if undefined is a valid element in your arrays, and you really need to check if anything is existing at that index or not(to avoid useless set of item at that index). this probably wont apply for you if you are not doing embedded development where clock cycles > everything else.

Answer (score 4):

I had to wrap techfoobar's answer in a `try`..`catch` block, like so:

```
try {
  if(typeof arrayName[index] == 'undefined') {
    // does not exist
  }
  else {
  // does exist
  }
} 
catch (error){ /* ignore */ }
```

...that's how it worked in chrome, anyway (otherwise, the code stopped with an error).

Comment: This should only have "broken" with an error if the variable `arrayName` itself (or `index`) did not exist. Simply accessing an undefined array element should not have resulted in an "error"?

Answer (score 4):

```
var demoArray = ['A','B','C','D'];
var ArrayIndexValue = 2;
if(ArrayIndexValue in demoArray){
   //Array index exists
}else{
   //Array Index does not Exists
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting ..what is the question actually?

Answer (score 3):

If elements of array are also simple objects or arrays, you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function:

```js
// search object
var element = { item:'book', title:'javasrcipt'};

[{ item:'handbook', title:'c++'}, { item:'book', title:'javasrcipt'}].some(function(el){
    if( el.item === element.item && el.title === element.title ){
        return true; 
     } 
});

[['handbook', 'c++'], ['book', 'javasrcipt']].some(function(el){
    if(el[0] == element.item && el[1] == element.title){
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: `some` is the modernest way around here. It also can even become a one-liner like `myArray.some(el => el.item === element.item && el.title === element.title)`

Answer (score 3):

Consider the array a:

```
var a ={'name1':1, 'name2':2}
```

If you want to check if 'name1' exists in a, simply test it with `in`:

```
if('name1' in a){
console.log('name1 exists in a')
}else
console.log('name1 is not in a')
```

Comment: "var a" is not an array object in your case, but a regular object. Should be var a = [ ... ]. I think this is what author needed.

Comment: This is how to check for the existence of a key in an object, not the presence of an index in an array.

Comment: The `in` operator seems to work with arrays too. Like `2 in [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` is true, but `6 in [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` is false. Just change your answer to array to be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for some thing like this.

Here is the following snippetr

```js
var demoArray = ['A','B','C','D'];
var ArrayIndexValue = 2;
if(demoArray.includes(ArrayIndexValue)){
alert("value exists");
   //Array index exists
}else{
alert("does not exist");
   //Array Index does not Exists
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I am going to use im my project today.  I have no idea why there were downvotes - this works best for my use case, which is server-side node.js / express.  Thank you

Comment: @mkrufky because that is not what this question is for. we've long had the ability prior to `Array.includes` to check if a value is an array, like `demoArray.indexOf(ArrayIndexValue) !== -1`. this question is about checking whether the index exists in the array, which is an entirely different problem

Answer (score 2):

One line validation. The simplest way.

```
return !!currentData[index];
```

Outputs

```
var testArray = ["a","b","c"]

testArray[5]; //output => undefined
testArray[1]; //output => "b"

!!testArray[5]; //output => false
!!testArray[1]; //output => true
```

Comment: It is of course okay, however, when everything become highly nested (harder to read), the way you shown is adding an extra level of complexity for readers. Even for experienced js coders, getting the logic in one read is difficult.

Comment: `testArray = [0, 0, 0]` will result in `false` for every index even though they are given.

Comment: This returns incorrect results if your array contains zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty) then these type of null and undefined check are hidden by the library.

So your code will look like this -

```
var currentData = new Array();

if (_.isEmpty(currentData)) return false;

Ti.API.info("is exists  " + currentData[index]);

return true;
```

It looks much more readable now.

Comment: Even if your answer is right, I would just think twice for this. Your code would become underscore.js dependent only for checking an empty value. Just do a simple wrapper function isset(v) { return  (typeof v !== 'undefined'); }

Answer (score 1):

This way is easiest one in my opinion.

```
var nameList = new Array('item1','item2','item3','item4');

// Using for loop to loop through each item to check if item exist.

for (var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {
if (nameList[i] === 'item1') 
{   
   alert('Value exist');
}else{
   alert('Value doesn\'t exist');
}
```

And Maybe Another way to do it is.

```
nameList.forEach(function(ItemList)
 {
   if(ItemList.name == 'item1')
        {
          alert('Item Exist');
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to check item exist or not

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--)
       if (this[i] == obj)
       return true;
    return false;
}

var myArray= ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

myArray.contains("Apple")
```

Comment: horribly inefficient.  what if I set `myArray[1000000] = 'Pear'` then your function will take forever.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
if(fruits.indexOf("Banana") == -1){
    console.log('item not exist')
} else {
 console.log('item exist')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this:

```
var tmp = ['a', 'b'];
index = 3 ;
if( tmp[index]){
    console.log(tmp[index] + '\n');
}else{
    console.log(' does not exist');
}
```

Comment: wrong.  what if `tmp = [0,0,0,0]` then tmp[3] should exist

Answer (score 0):

```
(typeof files[1] === undefined)?
            this.props.upload({file: files}):
            this.props.postMultipleUpload({file: files widgetIndex: 0, id})
```

Check if the second item in the array is undefined using the `typeof` and checking for `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof arrayName[index] == undefined) {
    console.log("Doesn't exist")
}
else {
console.log("does exist")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When trying to find out if an array index exists in JS, the easiest and shortest way to do it is through double negation.

```
let a = [];
a[1] = 'foo';
console.log(!!a[0])   // false
console.log(!!a[1])   // true
```

Comment: what about `a[1] = false`? `0`? `''`?

Comment: This returns incorrect results if your array contains zero.