# JavaScript check if array object exists or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add push a new object into the array if it doesn't exist?

I check this link: [How to check if array element exists or not in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107855/how-to-check-if-array-element-exists-or-not-in-javascript)

but not sure how to push the new object though!

```js
var element = [];

element['obj'] = 'one';

if (typeof element['obj']['bg'] === 'undefined') {

  console.log('not defined');

  element['obj']['bg'] = 'red';

  console.log(element);

} else {
  console.log('defined');
}
```

Comment: How about `element.push({'bg':'red'});` ? It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Could you be more specific?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `element['obj'] = 'one';` --> this initialises `element['obj']` to string, and then you want to add a key/value pair to that (string)?

Comment: You want to use `array` or `object`? `element['obj'] = 'one';` create attr `obj` on `element`, but its not account to length.

Comment: What structure are you expecting?

Comment: I don't understand what your code do. But if `element['obj'] = 'one'`, when you do `element['obj']['bg'] === 'undefined'` it's equals to `'one'['bg']`. I think It has no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var element = [];` defines an array and not an object. To push a new value into an array you need to use the `push` method :

```
element.push({'obj' : 'one'});
```

But I think you do not need to create an array  here, but just create an object. Declare your object like  `var element = {};`

Like this the line `element['obj'] = 'one';` works, you have an object with the key `obj` and the value `one`.

When you write `element['obj']['bg']` you try to access on an object inside an object. So before set the value `red` into you need create the object :

```
element['obj'] = {};
element['obj']['bg'] = 'red';
```

Full example :

```js
var element = {};

element['obj'] = {};

if (typeof element['obj']['bg'] === 'undefined') {

  console.log('not defined');

  element['obj']['bg'] = 'red';

  console.log(element);

} else {
  console.log('defined');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The element is of type `string`, not an object or an array.

Change the particular variable to an array:

```
var element = {};
element['obj'] = ['one'];
if ( typeof element['obj']['bg'] === 'undefined' ) {
    console.log('not defined');
    element['obj']['bg'] = 'red';
    console.log(element);
} else {
    console.log('defined');
}
```

Or better an object:

```
element['obj'] = {};
element['obj']['id'] = 'one';
```

The `string` objects are immutable objects.

Comment: But is set `bg` on an `array` is a good practice? Maybe we should wait OP to explain about what structure he expect.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Understand the situation... He's just setting a value. That's all! The OP doesn't mean any CSS or specific stuff here. `:)`

Comment: Yeah.. I agree you, this is the expect of the OP from his code.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting an empty array beforehand;

```
var element = [];

element['obj'] = 'one';

if ( typeof element['obj']['bg'] === 'undefined' ) {

    console.log('not defined');

    element['obj'] = [element['obj']];

    element['obj']['bg'] = 'red';

    console.log( element);

} else {
    console.log('defined');
}
```

Comment: Original value goes off!

Comment: But you cannot have both element['obj'] = 'one'; and element['obj']['bg'] = 'red';

Comment: You can have in a way... See my answer.

Comment: First one means the "obj" indexed value is a string, and the second one requires it to be an array. You have to choose!

Comment: I updated your answer to save the original value. If not, just revert it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = [];

element['obj'] = 'one';

if ( typeof element['obj']['bg'] === 'undefined' ) {

    console.log('not defined');

    element['obj'] = {'bg':'red'};

    console.log("My value:"+element['obj']['bg'] );

} else {
    console.log('defined');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o66uhd05/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way.

```
var element = [],item = [];

item['obj'] = 'one';
element.push(item);

if ( typeof element['obj']['bg'] === 'undefined' ) {

    console.log('not defined');

    item['bg']='red';

    element.push(item);

    console.log( element);

} else {
    console.log('defined');
}
```