# Changing conditionalPanel logic to allow selection rather than strict equality

Tags: r, shiny

Consider the following:

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

  checkboxGroupInput("Check1",label=h4 ("Fish:"), choices = c("Bass","Shark","Tuna")),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Check1 == 'Bass'",
    checkboxGroupInput("Check2",label=h4 ("Bass Types:"), choices = c("A","B","C"))
  )
))
```

**server.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
```

[image]

When Bass is checked, the new checkbox appears. Great.

[image]

But, if I were to select Shark as well, the Bass Types checkbox group disappears.

[image]

I would like to keep the Bass Types checkbox there as long as Bass is selected (so it should remain visible if Shark is selected).

I have already tried `condition = "'Bass' %in% input.Check1"`.

Comment: I don't use `shiny`, but if the condition argument to `conditionalPanel` uses R syntax, then changing `condition = "input.Check1 == 'Bass'"` to `condition = "'Bass' %in% input.Check1"` should be the right logic.

Comment: @lmo Unfortunately I've already tried that. Thanks, though.

Comment: Its a good idea to include what you have already tried in your question in order to reduce redundancy.

Comment: @lmo I think it uses JavaScript, after further research. Do you happen to know any JavaScript?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had the pleasure, but maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631803/check-for-element-in-array?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the links it contains will help.

Comment: @lmo I have marked the question as a duplicate.