# Is array[index] === undefined the always same as typeof array[index] === 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, typescript, v8

I need to see whether something there is an entry for an array index in Javascript and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107855/how-to-check-if-array-element-exists-or-not-in-javascript) say to uses (Essentially I changed it from === to !==):

> if(typeof arrayName[index] !== 'undefined')

IIUC this is the same as `arrayName[index] !== 'undefined'?

I experimented with it and it works, but I want to make sure I'm not missing any edge cases?

### Update

To clearify WRT to some answers given (Ran this on node `9.11.2`):

```
    let undefined = "Hello";
    console.log(undefined);
    let arrayName = [];
    if(arrayName[0] !== undefined) {
        console.log("Test passes");
        console.log("undefined is: ", undefined);
        console.log("arrayName[0] is: ", arrayName[0]);
    }
```

This prints:

```
Hello
Test passes
undefined is:  Hello
arrayName[0] is:  undefined
```

So it seems the answer is "No undefined could sometimes be redefind ..." ... and it's better to stick with `typeof array[index] === 'undefined'`, but as some have indicated, undefined cannot be redefined globally, so it should be fairly safe to use the shorter version.

Comment: Just stick with `void 0` if you're worried about `undefined` being redefined somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a very obscure edgecase:

```
let undefined = "confuse me!";
```

that means that

```
 "confuse me!" === undefined
```

might be `true` and

```
typeof undefined === "undefined"
```

might be `false`,  but if

```
 typeof arrayName[index] === "undefined"
```

is `true` then its definetly not  defined, however it might not be `undefined` :)

But as this is terrible, you don't really have to consider that.

Comment: OK - So Javascript allows us to use Javascript `undefined` as a variable name, hence the recommendation is to use 'undefined' explicitly ...

Comment: @ole no, that means that `"confuse me!" === undefined` might be `true` and `typeof undefined === "undefined"` might be false, but if `typeof arrayName[index] === "undefined"` then its definetly `undefined`

Comment: but this throws error `'undefined' has already been declared`

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli Just tried it in Node, I'm surprised to say that's correct. Older versions that was certainly not the case.

Comment: @hikmat then wrap it in a block.

Comment: OK - I updated the question with some additional testing around your illustration, and it looks like it's better to stick with the typeof check ... since undefined could be redefined ... Like you are saying.

Comment: @ole yeah but it can't be globally redeclared, only in your own code, and as you don't do this (i hope so) you don't have to consider this edgecase and `sth === undefined` is probably always more readable, faster to type etc.

Comment: Yeah I like the shorter version better for readability, and I'm using typescript, which I think also warns, so in my case it's fairly safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof arrayName[index] !== 'undefined')
```

is the same as

```
if(arrayName[index] !== undefined) // without quotes
```

But not as you stated:

> IIUC this is the same as `arrayName[index] !== 'undefined'?

```
if(arrayName[index] !== 'undefined') // this is not correct
```

---

[How dangerous is it in JavaScript, really, to assume undefined is not overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/how-dangerous-is-it-in-javascript-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritte)

Comment: The first two are not the same. `typeof` returns string always

Comment: Yeah, my bad, copy pasted and forgot to remove `typeof`, edited.

Comment: This is technically incorrect, they are not equivalent based on the syntax of quotes. My answer explains why.

Comment: You should read my answer again, I'm not using quotes on my second statement.

Comment: They are not equivalent. One is asking if an index's value is undefined. The other if it's data type is undefined. In my answer I showed how a variable value can be defined while it's type is undefined.

Comment: you're not correct, they're equivalent. Tell me one case where `(typeof arrayName[index] !== 'undefined') !== (arrayName[index] !== undefined)`, you won't find unless the edge case describe by @Jonas, but you won't have that in a real world scneario

Comment: @drewT the one checks if it contains the string `"undefined"`, but i guess thats rather a typo, the OP probably meant `=== undefined` and then they  are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined is a global variable, and as such its value can be reassigned. So it is possible that the variable `undefined` could not be undefined. But `typeof` an undefined value will always return `'undefined'`, so it is technically safer. In practice, most people wouldn't reassign `undefined`, so either works.