# How to convert a string in javascript to variable string combination

Tags: javascript, try-catch, eval

How to check (eval?) if a given string/variable is valid

If I try

```
getData('/img/webshop/'+product.images[551].slug+'/'+product.images[1].src')
```

I get 'Cannot read property slug of undefined' if array item [551] does not exist

My getData function contains a Try catch function to check if [551] exists but the error is allready generated when the getData function is called

I could solve this by adding back-ticks

```
getData(`'/img/webshop/'+product.images[551].slug+'/'+product.images[1].src'`)
```

and sending this like a string but then I need to convert this string in getData, (eval?) but this doesn't work. ( remains string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if array element exists or not in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107855/how-to-check-if-array-element-exists-or-not-in-javascript)

Comment: Short answer, check it **before** calling the method

Comment: Why would changing it to backticks solve the issue?

Comment: Sending a variable name as parameter won't send its content.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want to try catch in a seperate function, after calling the function. back-ticks make sending without error. I was a try..

Comment: @Cid I know how to check, I want it checked inside the function, calling the function gives an error. (thanks for editing my question :-) )

Comment: Well, then do it.

Comment: @Cid want to use the parameter to get the content